# how to not have a page refresh with HTML JQuery AJAX PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, page-refresh

I am trying to get the value of a selected radio button into a PHP session variable using Javascript/AJAX.  Everything works except the page refreshes.  Is there any way to not have the page refresh?

The HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="Standard"> Standard<br>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2-day"> 2-Day Air&#42<br>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="Overnight"> Overnight<br>
```

The Javascript/AJAX (with some alerts commented out):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name=shipping_method]").on('change', function(){
         var shipping_method  = $('input:radio[name=shipping_method]:checked').val();
/*                          alert (shipping_method); */
    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajax/shipping_method.php?shipping_method="+shipping_method,
            success : function(data){
/*                      alert(data);   */      
        },
                    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("problem: " + errorThrown);
            } 
    });
    });
});
```

The shipping_method.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
        $shipping_method = $_GET['shipping_method'];
        $_SESSION['shipping_method'] = $shipping_method;
?>
```

Comment: is the page refreshing when you click the radio button?

Comment: Nothing in the given code would cause a page refresh. Is there portions that you left out? Could you create a JSFiddle with the Client-side portions of the code
?

Comment: Please add more code , because for sure this code will not refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is happening but try preventing the default action. Change part of your code to this:

```
$("input[name=shipping_method]").on('change', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Why would the selection of a radio button cause a page refresh? That is not the "default action"

Comment: @PatBurke I have no idea but for some reason it does seem to be happening

Answer (score 0):

using event.preventDefault(); should fix your problem.